# Mongoose model use

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to build mongodb models in my system. I keep this info in my Business model:

```
const BusinessSchema = new Schema({
    businesId: {type: String},
    businessSubId: {type: String},
    subscriptionId: {type: String},
    accesId:{type:String},
    country: {type:String},
    city: {type:String},
    street: {type:String},
    products:[{productId: Number, role: Number, 
        dayOfDay:[{day: Date}], reservations:[{customerName:String, customerSurname:String,
             phoneNumber:Number,date: Date }]}],
})
```

After a while I think the reservation field will swell as it will take up too much data. What can I do to prevent this? I don't want to delete data. Is there a way to store this data more effectively?

Comment: Maybe you start by keeping the products in another collection, and then if necessary also keep reservations in another collection

Comment: @SuleymanSah i'm thinking about it but this time how can i associate it with booking and product with business

Comment: with mongoose populate (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) or mongodb lookup aggregation

Answer (score 0):

```
const BusinessSchema = new Schema({
    businesId: {type: String},
    businessSubId: {type: String},
    subscriptionId: {type: String},
    accesId:{type:String},
    country: {type:String},
    city: {type:String},
    street: {type:String},
    products:[
      {productId: Number,
      role: Number, 
        dayOfDay:[{day: Date}],
        reservations:[
          {customerName:String, 
          customerSurname:String,
             phoneNumber:Number,
             date: Date 
            
          }
         ]
      }
    ],
})
```

After doing this you have to create a model

```
const Business = mongoose.model('Business', BusinessSchema);
//now you can further use this object for data maniplation on this model like

Business.findOne({businesId:passId})
```

Comment: and also  instead ysing array of object you can create another collection ans store the _id here

Comment: more use of model you can find on mongoose official documantation 
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html